# Android Server socket connection to pc c# application get no connection

Tags: android, sockets, server, emulation

my first tcp socket connection when the android device (emulator) act as a client and the pc application act as server works fine (when you know to use 10.0.2.2 on client side as server adress).

Now I need the android side as server and the pc app as client and I get no connection at all.

Both are running on the same machine (android in emulator).

Android side

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9301);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

PC side

```
TcpClient  dataClient = new TcpClient();

dataClient.BeginConnect( "127.0.0.1", 9301, Do, MyData);
// 127.0.0.1 just for testing, later there will be the real ip adress of the device
```

In the telnet session for the emulator (5554) I add a redir like this

```
redir add tcp:9301:9301
```

Honestly I am absolutely not sure about the redir. Has anybody an idea what I am doing wrong, I am going mad about this.

For strange, with this code the client gets a connection to anywhat, the server gets no connection.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I did not find it out so I change the concept and change it also to a Andoid/client to PC/Server connection and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Just one of the first conclusions. It seems that the android emulator sometimes receive some less bytes than send. For example, I send a file with ~30000 bytes, I just receive 29987. Sometime it is OK. I made a test with a PC/c# client and the conection works perfect, no looses. When I test the android connection almoust 70 % of the file transfers corrupted because there are up to 15 bytes missing. When I change the server side to socket.SendFile the result are much better but also not perfekt. I update my protocol, so the client knows how much bytes shall come and in case of an receive error I can resend the file. I'm curious about the behaviour with a real device and wlan.